# If width of DIV is unspecified, does it always default to 100%?

Tags: html, css

If I have the HTML below, I always though that the outer Div would shrink to the size of the inner Div (based on how HTML Tables work).

I haven't seen this described anywhere, but it seems that div.outer, here, would be 100% the width of its container, right?

```
<div id="outer">
<div  id="inner" style="width:300px">
some text here
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes right, this is the logic of a block element `A block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element (container),`

Comment: this is probably the most relevant spec that describe all this : https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html

Comment: _"(based on how HTML Tables work)'_ What do tables have to do with divs?

Comment: Most block elements would, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Div is a block level element. And as Temani Afif said in the comment,

> A block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element

However this may change in the following situations:

```css
h1 {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    clear: both;
}
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.inner {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    width: 300px;
}

.outer-float-left {
    float: left;
}

.outer-float-right {
    float: right;
}

.outer-display-inline {
    display: inline;
}

.outer-display-inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
}

.outer-display-table {
    display: table;
}

.outer-position-relative {
    position: relative;
}

.outer-position-absolute {
    position: absolute;
}

.outer-position-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -100px;
    left: 0;
}

.outer9 {
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<h1>Default scenario. Outer div's float property set to none, display property set to block and position property set to static.</h1>
<div class="outer">
    This is Outer Div
    <div class="inner">
        This is Inner Div
    </div>
</div>

<h1>Outer div's float property set to left. Unless a width specified, float elements always take necessary width to wrap the elements inside and not more.</h1>
<div class="outer outer-float-left">
    This is Outer Div
    <div class="inner">
        This is Inner Div
    </div>
</div>

<h1>Outer div's float property set to right</h1>
<div class="outer outer-float-right">
    This is Outer Div
    <div class="inner">
        This is Inner Div
    </div>
</div>

<h1>Outer div's display property set to inline. Because inline elements can't contain block level elements, inner div's display property is changed to inline. Also notice that outer div's margin-bottom is missing. It's because you can't set width, max-width, height, max-height, margin-top and margin-bottom for inline elements.</h1>
<div class="outer outer-display-inline">
    This is Outer Div
    <div class="inner" style="display: inline;">
        This is Inner Div
    </div>
</div>

<h1>Outer div's display property set to inline-block</h1>
<div class="outer outer-display-inline-block">
    This is Outer Div
    <div class="inner">
        This is Inner Div
    </div>
</div>

<h1>Outer div's display property set to table</h1>
<div class="outer outer-display-table">
    This is Outer Div
    <div class="inner">
        This is Inner Div
    </div>
</div>

<h1>Outer div's position property set to relative</h1>
<div class="outer outer-position-relative">
    This is Outer Div
    <div class="inner">
        This is Inner Div
    </div>
</div>

<h1>Outer div's position property set to absolute</h1>
<div class="outer outer-position-absolute">
    This is Outer Div
    <div class="inner">
        This is Inner Div
    </div>
</div>

<h1 style="margin: 130px 0 75px;">Outer div's position property set to fixed.</h1>
<div class="outer outer-position-fixed">
    This is Outer Div (position - fixed)
    <div class="inner">
        This is Inner Div
    </div>
</div>
```

There may be other situations. This is all I can remember right now.
Hope that helps. Thanks. :)

You can read these articles if you need further clarification:

[All About Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

[For Display property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

[For position property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the property of the DIV
Check here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

to summarize, here are the common two properties
`display: block` will take 100% while
`display: inline-block` will shrink to width, or you provide it a width